# .tsx/typescript throws error "TS2307: Cannot find module 'History' only on Ubuntu?

Tags: macos, typescript, ubuntu, webpack-3, tsx

Facing a weird issue with a React/Typescript setup.

Running `webpack -p` on OSX/Windows compiles just fine with no errors from the TypeScript/TSX compiler at all.

However, on Ubuntu it will throw a TypeScript specific error, specifically:

`ERROR in [at-loader] ./src/scenes/Component.tsx:5:23
    TS2307: Cannot find module 'History'.`

The specific line which throws an error is:

`import {History} from "History";`

`package.json` has both normal and @types package for History:

`"@types/history": "4.6.0",`

`"history": "4.7.2",`

And again, I can run `webpack -p` with the exact same code, same webpack configuration and same version on OSX without it throwing an error. Process is the same! However, on Ubuntu the build will fail with the above error.

Answer (score 0):

The sinner was `awesome-typescript-loader`(at-loader). @3.2.x it threw this error; downgrading to @3.1.3 made it go away. This happened after upgrading packages apparently - but again, only seems to affect Ubuntu.